# iOS Safari html video doesn't play until the page is refreshed

Tags: html, ios, iphone, video, safari

The website has a simple HTML video as seen below:

```
 <video id="myVideo" controls preload="metadata" playsinline webkit-playsinline="true" poster="vid/vid_pic.jpg" width="640" height="360" style="background-color: black;" >
            <source src="vid/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

All browsers and devices play the video fine when you click the play button.  However iOS phones refuse to start the video, the users just keep tapping the play button but nothing happens..  They must refresh the page and then it works as intended.
I used to have a video wrapper but stripped it out because I thought it might have been the culprit.

The video is 720x1080, 2 minutes long, and optimized to be 36 MB.

Obviously this is not the ideal use case..  Any way to make a video start without a hitch on apple devices/safari?

Comment: Is the video completely loaded before clicking play?

Comment: I don't think so, Safari should be doing a short amount of 'preload' like a few seconds.  The testers said they just couldn't get it to start even after waiting a few minutes, while one reported it would start after a few play-tries.

Comment: did you find a way how to handle this ios issue?